# Function Python using "-->"

Tags: python, function

I have a code python like this

```
  @classmethod
    def create_card_batches(cls, number_of_cards: int) -> CardBatches:
        pass
```

But i dont understand ?

> -> CardBatches:

What is this ? Anyone explain for me please ?

Comment: This function returns ``CardBatches``

Comment: → [“
PEP 0483 -- The Theory of Type Hints
”](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)